# How to convert SQL scalar subquery to SQLAlchemy expression

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I need a litle help with expressing in SQLAlchemy language my code like this:

```
SELECT
    s.agent_id,
    s.property_id,
    p.address_zip,
    (
        SELECT v.valuation
        FROM property_valuations v WHERE v.zip_code = p.address_zip
        ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(v.as_of, s.date_sold))
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS back_valuation,
FROM sales s
JOIN properties p ON s.property_id = p.id
```

Inner subquery aimed to get property value from table `propert_valuations` with columns (`zip_code INT, valuation DECIMAL, as_if DATE`) closest to the date of sale from table `sales`. I know how to rewrite it but I completely stuck on `order_by` expression - I cannot prepare subquery to pass ordering member later.

Currently I have following queries:

```
subquery = (
    session.query(PropertyValuation)
    .filter(PropertyValuation.zip_code == Property.address_zip)
    .order_by(func.abs(func.datediff(PropertyValuation.as_of, Sale.date_sold)))
    .limit(1)
)

query = session.query(Sale).join(Sale.property_)
```

How to combine these queries together?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How to combine these queries together?

Use [`as_scalar()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.as_scalar), or [`label()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#scalar-selects):

```
subquery = (
    session.query(PropertyValuation.valuation)
    .filter(PropertyValuation.zip_code == Property.address_zip)
    .order_by(func.abs(func.datediff(PropertyValuation.as_of, Sale.date_sold)))
    .limit(1)
)

query = session.query(Sale.agent_id,
                      Sale.property_id,
                      Property.address_zip,
                      # `subquery.as_scalar()` or
                      subquery.label('back_valuation'))\
        .join(Property)
```

Using `as_scalar()` limits returned columns and rows to 1, so you cannot get the whole model object using it (as `query(PropertyValuation)` is a select of all the attributes of `PropertyValuation`), but getting just the *valuation* attribute works.

> but I completely stuck on order_by expression - I cannot prepare subquery to pass ordering member later.

There's no need to pass it later. Your current way of declaring the subquery is fine as it is, since SQLAlchemy can [automatically correlate FROM objects to those of an enclosing query](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#correlated-subqueries). I tried creating models that somewhat represent what you have, and here's how the query above works out (with added line-breaks and indentation for readability):

```
In [10]: print(query)
SELECT sale.agent_id AS sale_agent_id,
       sale.property_id AS sale_property_id,
       property.address_zip AS property_address_zip,
       (SELECT property_valuations.valuation
        FROM property_valuations 
        WHERE property_valuations.zip_code = property.address_zip
        ORDER BY abs(datediff(property_valuations.as_of, sale.date_sold))
        LIMIT ? OFFSET ?) AS back_valuation 
FROM sale
JOIN property ON property.id = sale.property_id
```

Comment: Starting SQLAlchemy 1.4, `as_scalar()` has been replaced with `scalar_subquery()`

Comment: I’d appreciate if the answer could be updated to use `scalar_subquery()` instead.