# Need to convert a SQL statement, that has count columns, to SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have made the following query

```
select
    id,
    name, 
    (select count(*) from users where company_id=companies.id) as num_candidates, 
    (select count(*) from users where company_id=companies.id and status=1) as num_evaluating ,
    (select count(*) from users where company_id=companies.id and created_at between '9/12/2019' and '9/19/2019') as num_last_week 
    from companies order by num_candidates DESC limit 10;
```

Specifically I'm having issue with the non standard columns that are taking a count. Currently I have roughly as a test (based on cobbling some examples together)

```
num_candidates = db.session.query(models.User.id).filter(models.User.company_id == models.Company.id).count().label("num_candidates")

query = db.session.query(models.Company.id, 
                     models.Company.name,
                     num_candidates).order_by("num_candidates").all()
```

But this of course gives me errors.  Any ideas how I should properly construct the SQL Alchemy?

Comment: "But this of course gives me errors"---those error messages probably contain helpful information. What do they say? Please read [ask].

Comment: `Query.count()` executes the query and returns an integer. My guess is that your error is an AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'label' or such. The "non-standard columns" are scalar subqueries. Please see how to form them for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37392773/how-to-convert-sql-scalar-subquery-to-sqlalchemy-expression, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654336/generate-sql-with-subquery-as-a-column-in-select-statement-using-sqlalchemy